# Representing an equation as a canvas object in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program which deals with symbolic equations rendered on a canvas object in Tkinter. The program needs to be able to draw an equation, and then when users clicks on the equation, I need to know which symbol they clicked on.

I've considered a few ways of doing this:

I can manually write a math rendering program which tells the Canvas object what symbols to put there, and then they're just text objects whose click events I can detect the normal way. However, this seems like a lot of redundant effort, and I won't be able to make it very pretty.

I could render the equation as an image using a library, and then write my own code to figure out approximately where the different symbols would be, then detect clicks and decide what symbol the user clicked by the position of the click. This is hacky and sounds unreliable. Plus it means I need to write the code to detect where the symbols are.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

It is probably the best idea to get the equation from a string.

This may not be the best way to do it, but it's still a valid option, you can get the string as it is and then replace the x value with what what ever x is using the `eval()` function.

```
equation = "2^x"

for x in range(length of graph):
    x2 = x-1 #to draw a line from this point to the previous one. 
    canvas.create_line(x, eval(equation), x2, eval(equation.replace('x', "x2"))
```

Comment: I'm trying to represent the equation symbolically, not as a graph.